Prettier failing with "Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed with message: js_source_text is not defined"
I'm using Prettier, along with the plugin prettier-plugin-apex in VS Code, to format Salesforce classes and Visual Force pages etc.
It works (formats my docs on Save) most of the time, but now some, but not all, VF Pages (.page files) are failing to format with this error:
[Error - 10:42:57 AM] Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed with message: js_source_text is not defined
  Code: -32603 

I've searched for this error, and even just for Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed with message: js_source_text is not defined with nothing really useful returned.
It's really quite odd that it works for some files and not others, even though they have the same extension.
Any ideas what's going and how I can fix this?

Have you checked the config as per https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier

@georgethomas Yes, it's all set up as recommended. It does work for some file types (Apex files) but not VF Pages. Thanks.

It works for me, can you check the file .prettierrc inside your project folder. Mine has these values https://www.decodeforce.com/code/-O-bwNuNWJaEyS5_vthI.

@georgethomas - this is mine: https://www.decodeforce.com/code/-O-pIRNHUAwO3dbwuuq6
Seems to be functionaly the same, esp the page & component bit

Can you try the format document option and see what happens? 

Same result:
[Error - 11:54:26 AM] Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed.
Message: Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed with message: js_source_text is not defined
Code: -32603
It works correctly for Apex files, just not for VF pages/Components

As this issue for Visualforce extension suggests, the Visualforce Lanaguage Server fails to format Visualforce page/component only if the code contains <style>  . . . . </style> tag(s).
Not an answer to your question, unfortunately, but I am unable to add this as a comment (not enough reputation on this particular StackOverflow site).
